# Network profile activity list has gone on a diet

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, stackexchange.com, network-profile

The network profile activity view only takes up as much space as the longest item in the list, instead of expanding to the full width of the page. This is made extra annoying by the fact that expanding items on that list usually causes it to take up more space, resizing the entire table.

[image: flexible space]

This impacts the inbox view as well, and seems to be handled on the per-site profiles with the following CSS:

```
.history-table > tbody > tr > td:last-child {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Also of note is that on per-site profiles, revisions shown in this list are expandable, but on the network profile they're not. That could easily be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), which is fine, but since it's inconsistent I thought I'd make a point of mentioning it.

Comment: With regard to the expandable revisions, this is technically [status-planned].. we just haven't gotten to it yet.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the update!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed -- the [activity](https://stackexchange.com/users/152015/tim-stone?tab=activity) and [inbox](https://stackexchange.com/users/152015/tim-stone?tab=inbox) tabs take up the width of the page now.